# Is this how adding a python list to numpy arrary is expected to work?

Tags: numpy, python-2.x

Adding a python list to a numpy array produces the same result as adding a python float to a numpy array. If the array is cast as a list when it is added, the then it behaves like `extend()` as I was hoping the first calculation would behave. Is there a good reason why the behavior is the same adding a list vs float to an array?

```
In [3]: [-3.0] + numpy.linspace(0, 2, 5)

Out[3]: array([-3. , -2.5, -2. , -1.5, -1. ])

In [4]: -3.0 + numpy.linspace(0, 2, 5)

Out[4]: array([-3. , -2.5, -2. , -1.5, -1. ])

In [5]: [-3.0] + list(numpy.linspace(0, 2, 5))

Out[5]: [-3.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with lists, try `numpy.array([-3.0]) + numpy.linspace(0, 2, 5)`. And yes, this is expected, the + symbol for numpy only means addition, not concatenation.

Comment: okay, thanks! that's a good way to think about it. If i want list behavior i just need to use .extend()